# Cannot make git commits from terminal whilst project is open in VScode?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am working on my first ever project using git. And I was periodically making commits in my terminal with

```
$git add something.js
$git commit -m "Something"
```

Only to find 2 hours later when I refreshed my repo on GitHub that it had not been updated. Instead I find I have to commit through VScode with a little button at the bottom. Once I did this all of my commits went through. How do I disable this? So I can just commit from my terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to `git push` for the code to show up on github.